# php curl fails whereas command line curl works

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

i am trying to use the following curl to get some data from google map using php

```
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, trim($_url));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.35.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 0);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

However this is returning following from google maps api:
stdClass Object
(
    [error_message] => This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console
    [results] => Array
        (
        )

```
[status] => REQUEST_DENIED
)
```

When i try to use the same url via command line curl it works.

```
curl -v https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=Salt+Lake+City%2CUT&key=AIasasasasaasasg
```

i see the following in the php header:

```
> GET /maps/api/geocode/json?address=Salt+Lake+City%2CUT&key=AIasasasasassahg HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
 Host: maps.googleapis.com
Accept: */*


< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Sat, 06 Dec 2014 14:14:13 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
< Vary: Accept-Language
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
* Server mafe is not blacklisted
< Server: mafe
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=0.02
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host maps.googleapis.com left intact
```

Whereas the curl header looks like

```
CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.googleapis.com
*    start date: 2014-11-20 09:42:23 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-02-18 00:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: maps.googleapis.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /maps/api/geocode/json?address=Salt+Lake+City%2CUT HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
```

Basically the GET is different.
Is there something I can do to make this work? i have set the api to be accepted from any referer. is

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for many (frustrating) hours. You have to replace the "&" separating your parameters with `&amp;`.

The reason for why it actually worked with CLI curl (and any browser), is unknown to me: without the character escaping, the 'key' parameter doesn't seem to be sent at all and yet it makes the googlemaps api return the requested data like everything is all right ...

Answer (score 0):

```
bad:  GET /maps/api/geocode/json?address=Salt+Lake+City%2CUT  
good: GET /maps/api/geocode/json?address=Salt+Lake+City%2CUT&key=AIasasasasassahg
```

Obviously your are missing the key parameter in the URL.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, trim($_url));
```

And from this code it looks like a bad `$_url` must be the problem.